# what is "!" means in this function?

Tags: scala

```
def checkHappynumber(n: Int): Boolean = {
val set = scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]()
var num: Int = n
while(num != 1) {
  var newnum: Int = 0
  while (num != 0) {
    newnum += (num % 10) * (num % 10)
    num /= 10
  }
  if(!set.add(newnum)){
    return false;
  }
  num = newnum
}
return true
```

}

What's "!" role in there? the if(!set.add(newnum))? I know that hashset can't have repeated value. The only question is how "!" works here.

Comment: Note that code is pretty much not idiomatic for **Scala**, it looks more like **Java** code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is a negation operator (`!true` is `false`, `!false` is `true`). `HashSet.add` returns `true` if element was not present in the set (successfully added), `false` otherwise. This code returns `false` if element was already present in the hashset (trying to add it for the second time).

Here's [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/mutable/HashSet.html#add(elem:A):Boolean) of `add` method.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala, `!foo` is *syntactic sugar* for `foo.unary_!`. In other words, `!foo` is just calling the method named `unary_!` just like `foo.bar` is calling the method `bar`. There is nothing special about `unary_!` in that regard.

In your case, this means that `!set.add(newnum)` is just syntactic sugar for `set.add(newnum).unary_!`.

Like with all other methods, if you want to know what the method does, you first need to find where it is defined. In this case, the return type of [`scala.collection.mutable.Set.add`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.2/scala/collection/mutable/Set.html#add-4ad) is [`scala.Boolean`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.2/scala/Boolean.html) which means the specific method being called is [`scala.Boolean.unary_!`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.2/scala/Boolean.html#unary_!-0), which is defined like this:

> ## `def unary_!: Boolean`
>
> Negates a Boolean expression.
>
> - `!a` results in `false` if and only if `a` evaluates to `true` and
> - `!a` results in `true` if and only if `a` evaluates to `false`.
>
> *Returns*: the negated expression